# Windows 7 Ultimate - simultaneous use

Tags: windows-7, license

If I have a retail copy of Windows 7 Ultimate (which comes with both 32- and 64-bit variants in the same pack, can I use the 32-bit version on one machine and the 64-bit version on another machine **at the same time**, or would I be violating the EULA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> or would I be violating the EULA?

It wouldn't hurt to read the EULA. Even a bit of it. Your answer starts on page 1, it finishes on page 2:

> `2. INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS.`
>
> a. One Copy per Computer. You may install one copy of the software on one computer. That computer is the “licensed computer.”
>
> b. Licensed Computer. You may use the software on up to two processors on the licensed computer at one time. Unless otherwise provided in these license terms, you may not use the software on any other computer.
>
> c. Number of Users. Unless otherwise provided in these license terms, only one user may use the software at a time.
>
> **d. Alternative Versions. The software may include more than one version, such as 32-bit and 64-bit. You may install and use only one version at one time.**

Answer (score 4):

One key, one license.

Comment: no keys, no licences ...

Comment: That really should be "One license, one instance". If I have a corporate VLA key then I could have 100 licenses.

Answer (score 1):

One Product Key = One Installation at the same time.